# GitHub.com vs Github.io

Tags: github

I'm a bit lost about the difference between submitting a file to GitHub vs GitHub IO, could someone please explain?

Comment: I don’t think you’re branching a file. May you explain your issue?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Shan is asking about Github IO and Github, not Git.

Comment: Git is a tool for version control.  GitHub is a commercial service that can host Git repositories.  (It isn't required for using Git.)  GitHub Pages are a quick way to host static web pages via Git repositories.

Comment: So my professor wants us to BRANCH a file new assignment into GitHub io, what is GitHubio?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a blog post that explains the purpose of `github.io`:

https://github.blog/2013-04-05-new-github-pages-domain-github-io/

`github.io` is dedicated to the "GitHub Pages" product.  It is not really relevant to what you need.  You just want GitHub.